# How do I construct this elasticsearch query object?

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents are indexed like this:

```
{
    title: "stuff here",
    description: "stuff here",
    keywords: "stuff here",
    score1: "number here",
    score2: "number here"
}
```

I want to perform a query that:

- Uses the title, description, and keywords fields for matching the text terms.
- It doesn't have to be complete match.  Eg. If someone searches "I have a big nose", and "nose" is in one of the document titles but "big" is not, then this document should still be returned.

Edit: I tried this query and it works. Can someone confirm if this is the right way to do it? Thanks.

```
{
    query:{
        'multi_match':{
            'query': q,
            'fields': ['title^2','description', 'keywords'],
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your way is definitely the way to go!

The [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query.html) query is usually the one that you want to expose to the end users, while the [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) is similar, but also more powerful and dangerous since it exposes the [lucene query syntax](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html). Rule of thumb: don't use query string if you don't need it.

Also, searching on multiple fields is easy just providing the list of fields you want to search on, as you did, without the need for a [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will create the query you can use. I wrote it in **c#** but it will work in other languages in the same way.

What you need to do is to create a **BooleanQuery** and set that at least 1 of its condition has to match. Then add a condition for every document field you want to be checked with **Occur.SHOULD** enum value:

```
BooleanQuery searchQuery = new BooleanQuery();
searchQuery.SetMinimumNumberShouldMatch(1);

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "title", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
Query titleQuery = parser.Parse("I have a big nose");
searchQuery.Add(titleQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "description", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
Query descriptionQuery = parser.Parse("I have a big nose");
searchQuery.Add(titleQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "keywords", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
Query keywordsQuery = parser.Parse("I have a big nose");
searchQuery.Add(titleQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

Query queryThatShouldBeExecuted.Add(searchQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Here is the link to an example in java http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/apache/lucene/search/TestBooleanMinShouldMatch.java.html

Comment: The question was about elasticsearch. I understand this is the related lucene code to do that, even though you don't really need a boolean query here, since you can use the lucene multifieldqueryparser. Anyway  I don't really think this answer is useful when working with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

The according JSON object to perform a HTTP Post request would be this:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "I have a big nose",
          "default_field": "title"
        }
      },
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "I have a big nose",
          "default_field": "description"
        }
      },
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "I have a big nose",
          "default_field": "keywords"
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Multimatch is a wrapper for query_string queries both is valid. You might want to delete the ^2 on the title field except you want to boost that field.

Comment: Is there a way to do custom scoring with bool? For example...I want to do score1 * score2 * weight.  Could you show me how to incorporate that in the bool? THanks

Comment: I have not worked with scores so far but I think if you replace the query_string queries with custom_score_queries it would work too.

Comment: @MeiSign multi_match is not a wrapper for query string. The query string is parsed and exposes the lucene syntax (powerful but potentially dangerous), while the match query is analyzed but much more simple and less dangerous. Go for match or multimatch unless you need something else!